# An error occurred while the starting Spyder kernel

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I keep getting the following error. I have restarted my computer, uninstalled/reinstalled Anaconda, uninstalled spyder/spyder-kernels and reinstalled via the Anaconda Prompt, and still keep getting this error. New to Python, so any help is appreciated.

### Error Traceback

```
An error occurred while starting the kernel
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\k.g\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "C:\Users\k.g\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
    File "C:\Users\k.g\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\__main__.py", line 11, in 
    start.main()
    File "C:\Users\k.g\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 287, in main
    import_spydercustomize()
    File "C:\Users\k.g\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 39, in import_spydercustomize
    import spydercustomize
    File "C:\Users\k.g\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 27, in 
    from IPython.core.getipython import get_ipython
    File "C:\Users\k.g\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 54, in 
    from .core.application import Application
    File "C:\Users\k.g\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 23, in 
    from traitlets.config.application import Application, catch_config_error
    File "C:\Users\k.g\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\__init__.py", line 6, in 
    from .application import *
    File "C:\Users\k.g\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 100, in 
    class LevelFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'Formatter'
```

### Conda Info

```
> conda info

     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\Users\k.g\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\k.g\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\k.g\.condarc
          conda version : 4.7.12
    conda-build version : 3.18.8
         python version : 3.7.3.final.0
       virtual packages :
       base environment : C:\Users\k.g\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\k.g\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\k.g\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\k.g\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\k.g\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\k.g\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\k.g\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.7.12 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.3 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17134
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Comment: Does anyone else find it strange that `site-packages` is directly under `lib`? Or is that just a Windows thing? On Unix and Linux, I'm used to it being under `lib/python3.7` or whatever other Python version.  Anyway, could you please include the output of `conda info` in the body of the question?

Comment: Added that output from the prompt.

Comment: Most probably you have a file called `logging.py` somewhere in your `C:\Users\k.g\` directory which is interfering with the Python `logging` module.